# I can not run HHVM on CentOS

Tags: centos, hhvm

I have installed hhvm on CentOS and when I try to run returns me an error:

> Starting hhvm: Possible bad config node: dFile

in /var/log/hhvm/error.log ist

> Unable to open pid file www.pid for write

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is your HHVM pid file configured to live? In `/etc/hhvm/server.hdf` or similar, do you have a `PidFile =` setting?

I set mine to `PidFile = /var/run/hhvm/pid`. I then did a `mkdir /var/run/hhvm`.

Comment: You're right in the configuration file I missed: PidFile = /var/run/hhvm/pid